# WebException was unhandled when reading from database

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, exception

What I am doing is very simple. I just need to connect to a SQL database and read the information from the table. I am sure that I am missing something silly. I am using C#, SQL Sever, and WPF. The connectionstring shown is the one that the data source builder provided so I assume it is correct. I tested the connection with it and it was successful. I am attaching some code and images to help you help me solve my problem.

Code:

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=USSW7DEVWS16\\DEVELOPER;Initial Catalog=acrGIS;Integrated Security=True";

    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.acrObjects", con))
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string Object = reader.GetString(0);
            string Comment = reader.GetString(1);
            string OStreet = reader.GetString(2);
            string OCity = reader.GetString(3);
            string OState = reader.GetString(4);
            string OZip = reader.GetString(5);
            string OSpec = reader.GetString(6);

            arcObjects.Add(new acrObject() { Object_Num = Object, Comments = Comment, Street = OStreet, City = OCity, State = OState, Zip = OZip, Spec = OSpec });
        }
        foreach (acrObject objects in arcObjects)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(objects.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Here is my Class as well as my List and Connection Definitions:

```
class acrObject
{
    public string Object_Num {get; set;}
    public string Comments{get; set;}
    public string Street {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}
    public string State{get; set;}
    public string Zip {get; set;}
    public string Spec {get; set;}
    public override string  ToString()
    {
              return string.Format("Object Number: {0}, Comments: {1}, Street: {2}, City: {3}, State: {4}, Zip: {5}, Spec: {6}", Object_Num, Comments, Street, City, State, Zip, Spec);
    }
}



System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;

        List<acrObject> arcObjects = new List<acrObject>();
```

Images of the exception:

[image]

It happens on the line:

```
while (reader.Read())
```

What is even more weird is sometimes the error is not thrown and it skips all of the code. So it never evens tries to show the messagebox which I find is so weird. Thank you for your help. If you have any more questions or would like me to post more of my code let me know and I will be happy to.

Showing Breakpoint and Call Stack:

[image]

Here is the exception thrown when I perform a try/catch:

[image]

Comment: If you are having a hard time seeing the image, just CTRL++ until you are able to read the picture :)

Comment: Did you try adding `try-catch` to see which exception it gives?

Comment: On the message box above, click "View Detail" and check what the "Inner exception" says.

Comment: None of the code you posted does any web work. Look at the call stack to find out where in your code the error occured.

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Comment: It's odd that your "autos" window should say that reader is null when you are getting this kind of exception.  I agree with Ben, look at your call stack and put a break point and check the value of reader before the call.

Comment: I added the call stack image.

Comment: The entire exception message would be more helpful that a screen shot; click "Copy exception detail to clipboard" from the message and paste that text instead of the screen shot. Also, what is the "it" in "it was successful"? What happens if you connect to the database from SQL Server Studio or something and type "SELECT * FROM dbo.acrObjects"?

Comment: I have updated the question once again with more detail. Thanks to those of you who have already inputted. @Dour High Arch, the connection was successful. "It" = the connection. When I run the query in SQL it returns the correct information.

Comment: HA! I kind of want to jump off a bridge right now... I spent 2 hours looking for the answer to this problem... Decided to give up and go get lunch. Came back and the first thing I noticed was that I spelled my table name wrong.... acrObjects should be arcObjects.... Oh the joys of being a programmer. Thank you everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure sure the identity your application has access to the `dbo` schema, and also make sure you created `arcObjects` in the `dbo` schema.

1. You can check the login's default schema by executing `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()`. Alternately, you can find the login in your database under Security > Users and viewing its properties. You can examine the default schema as well as any additional schemas it owns. For example, you might add the user to `db_owner`, or perhaps `db_datareader`/`db_datawriter` if you don't want the identity to have full permissions.
2. Checking the schema the table belongs to:

Execute the following SQL in a new query window:

```
select t.name as table_name, s.name as schema_name from sys.tables as t 
    inner join sys.schemas as s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'arcObjects')
```

If the table belongs to `dbo`, it should say `dbo` under the `schema_name` column. If it does not, move the table into `dbo`:

```
 ALTER SCHEMA dbo 
 TRANSFER [schema listed in schema_name column].arcObjects
```

Alternately, you can browse the tables in the object explorer. The tables will be listed in [schema].[table name] format.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I would check this?

Comment: They are all showing there correctly.. I even added the database as a datasource to visual studio and the table and data is there.. I don't understand what is going on. It is not the first time I have done this haha.

Comment: I am going to put your answer as the correct one since it would have worked if that was my problem. Check out my comment above to see my real problem haha. :p  Thanks Again.